python SyncManager used by remote processes: how to identify shared objects
Using a SyncManager, if a group of processes need to share more than one dict() (say), the typical recipe is for the starting process to create them, and pass proxies to subprocesses.
However, in the case of remote managers, this method of identifying the shared dictionaries isn't available. What is the best way to establish the identity of the shared objects?
If each subprocess calls SyncManger.dict() three times, are they guaranteed to get back proxies to the same three objects in the same order?
Is a good way to deal with this to have one "designated" dict (say, the first one called) which is a place where other objects can be registered? Is this a good use for a Namespace or are they just used for sharing constants?

The question is about identifying shared objects in Python's multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager when used by remote processes.
Simple Explanation:
When you use SyncManager in Python to manage shared objects, the objects you share (e.g., dictionaries, lists) can be used across processes, even remotely. Each shared object is assigned a unique ID or "key" when it is created.

Thanks! How do I access objects by "key" - I don't see that in the interface?
